# Web page connection through VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a currency calculater in VBA excel, and I cannot make it work. My code below show how far I am. My problem is that I cannot get the calculated number on the web page into excel (the sDD). This code only concerns from DKK to USD, which I will change later, but right now the problem is to get the exchange amount into Excel. Hope you can help!

**code:**

```
Sub currency_1()
    Dim Price As Double
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Price = Range("C4")
    IE.Visible = True
 IE.Navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter/#from=DKK;to=USD;amt=" & Price

 Do

    DoEvents

Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument


Set Doc = IE.Document

On Error Resume Next

Dim sDD As Double

sDD = Doc.getElementById("yui_3_18_1_1_1467628123397_410").Value

IE.Quit

Range("E4").Value = sDD

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still relevant in this day and age, but for a great many years I used the MsXml active X control. Usually version 3 or version 6. You could probably download the Text (rather than the Xml) for the page, but you'd be better trying to connect to a web service.

Comment: I am not familiar with your way here but I extracted many times from yahoo and I think this link will help you: [link](http://access-excel.tips/get-foreign-exchange-rate-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm pretty sure your problem is I cannot find the "yui_3_18_1_1_1467628123397_410" on the source code for that website.

Your On error resume next is really bad coding and will hide this issue. Remove it, run it again and see if it bugs out